# Reusing component with absolute position in a flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs

I simply can not wrap my head around positioning. In my app I have some tiles (or think playing cards). these cards are dynamically created, say I want a number in the upper left and lower right. I have some code like

React code

```
<div  className='PlayingCard'>
    <span classname='upperNumber'> {number} </span>
    <span classname='LowerNumber'> {number} </span>
<div>
```

css

```
.PlayingCard{
   width: 50px;
   height: 100px;
}

.upperNumber{
   position: absolute;
   top: 5px;
   left 5px;
}

.lowerNumber{
   position: absolute;
   top: 80px;
   left 40px;
}
```

So the issue is that absolute is relative to the only a container that is also absolute. making playing card absolute will make A single card display correctly.  But in my case the cards will be in a flexbox so I can't make it absolute.  Is there a way to make a complicated component that has internal absolute (or absolute like) positions but have it be use in a flexbox or any other way I'd like.

For the moment I've make the numbers in the card relative however some of the cards have a variable number of items in them so it shifts things unacceptably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of typos in it

here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-elbakyan-m6s4e

its className not classname, missing closing div tag , lowerNumber className is different than class (case).  also missing semi-colon on left property.

to position to the bottom right. using bottom and right 5px.

put position relative on the PlayingCard

```
      <div className="PlayingCard">
        <span className="upperNumber">{number}</span>
        <span className="lowerNumber">{number}</span>
      </div>
```

```
.PlayingCard {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
}

.upperNumber {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

.lowerNumber {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: That was just an example typed freehand the actual code is more complicated so was trying to highlight the issue.  But you answered me,  Relative on the parent, which is odd because that is not an absolute type thought relative with 0 offset is just normal positioning but then acts as the reference for absolute under it. I would have never figured that out.  thanks.